# Highcharts not rendering plotbands correctly on first load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using 6 different plotband arrays to create colours in the background of my highcharts - I use it to show movement of a vehicle in a country.

When the graph loads first it squashes all the bands together (doesn't leave white space in between them) but on refresh or 2nd load of the same data it shows up perfectly.

I am not getting any javascript errors, also tried not caching the js file (by adding the timestamp to the request). I also tested this after completely clearing my browser cache.

Any ideas? It used to happen every now and then when i only had one plotband but it seems to be happening constantly since i added in a few more

Tested it in both firefox and chrome and both have the same issue

Its a large file but i have a snippet of my code below

```
        for(var i = 0; i < speedArray.length; i++) 
        {
            var fromTimestamp   = speedArray[i][0];
            var toTimestamp     = speedArray[i][1];
            
            $('#fuelLevelGraph').highcharts().xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: fromTimestamp,
            to: toTimestamp,
            color: '#ff33ff'
            });
        }
    
        for(var i = 0; i < speedArrayUK.length; i++) 
        {
            var fromTimestamp   = speedArrayUK[i][0];
            var toTimestamp     = speedArrayUK[i][1];
            
            $('#fuelLevelGraph').highcharts().xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: fromTimestamp,
            to: toTimestamp,
            color: '#ff9999'
            });
        }
    
    
        for(var i = 0; i < speedArrayIRL.length; i++) 
        {
            var fromTimestamp   = speedArrayIRL[i][0];
            var toTimestamp     = speedArrayIRL[i][1];
            
            $('#fuelLevelGraph').highcharts().xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: fromTimestamp,
            to: toTimestamp,
            color: '#66ff66'
            });
        }   
    
        for(var i = 0; i < speedArrayFR.length; i++) 
        {
            var fromTimestamp   = speedArrayFR[i][0];
            var toTimestamp     = speedArrayFR[i][1];
            
            $('#fuelLevelGraph').highcharts().xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: fromTimestamp,
            to: toTimestamp,
            color: '#6666ff'
            });
        }   
    
    
        for(var i = 0; i < speedArraySP.length; i++) 
        {
            var fromTimestamp   = speedArraySP[i][0];
            var toTimestamp     = speedArraySP[i][1];
            
            $('#fuelLevelGraph').highcharts().xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: fromTimestamp,
            to: toTimestamp,
            color: '#ffff00'
            });
        }
    
        for(var i = 0; i < speedArrayBE.length; i++) 
        {
            var fromTimestamp   = speedArrayBE[i][0];
            var toTimestamp     = speedArrayBE[i][1];
            
            $('#fuelLevelGraph').highcharts().xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: fromTimestamp,
            to: toTimestamp,
            color: '#996633'
            });
        }
```

I have made sure to sort each to avoid the highcharts error #15. The images below will show you what happens

[Image: First load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzZ9Q.png)

[Image: After Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsfs9.png)

Comment: How do you load the data?

Comment: Thanks for the response - i just figured out what was happening. The data was coming back in a different order on first load -- it was from an external mssql table. So specifying the order fixed the issue, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The data source (mssql table) was ordering the results incorrectly on first load -- forcing the order (using ORDER BY) fixed the issue